# updating data extension from front end javascript using ajax and json code resource

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, jquery, cloudpage, ajax

I have a preference center page to update preference values using toggle button(check boxes) without a save/submit button, so each toggle button should be processed separately.
I am making ajax call to a json code resource which interacts with the data extension.
Whats wrong in my code i am getting 500 internal server error.
landing page:

```
<script runat="server" language="javascript">
  Platform.Load("Core","1");
  var PrefDE = DataExtension.Init("external key here");
  try{
     var transemail = document.getElementById('id of checkbox');
    var resident = Attribute.GetValue("_subscriberkey");
    var res = resident+'_PROMOTIONAL_EMAIL';
      var prefvalue = Platform.Function.Lookup('Preference_DE_Staging','preference_value', 'resident_preference_id',res);
    
    if (prefvalue_temail == "True"){
      var temp = "checked";
     Variable.SetValue("@temp",temp);
      var changevalue = "False";
      transemail.addEventListener('click',validateTemail,true);
      function validateTemail(){
       $(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "url of json code resource page", 
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data:{"preference_value":changevalue,"resident_preference_id":res}
      success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);  
      }
           error: function(err) {
        console.log(err);  
      }
   
  });
});

      }
     
    }
      else{
       temp=""; 
         Variable.SetValue("@temp",temp);
      }

  }
  catch(e){
   Write(Stringify(e)); 
  }
```

json code resource:

```
%%[  
    Platform.Load("Core", "1");
 var PrefDE1 = DataExtension.Init("external key");
 SET @preference_value = RequestParameter('preference_value')
    SET @resident_preference_id = RequestParameter('resident_preference_id')
 
var data = PrefDE1.Rows.Update({
            preference_value: "False" }
                                            , ["resident_preference_id"], [@resident_preference_id]);
]%%
{
 "preferencevalue" : %%=v((@preference_value))=%%
"resident_preference_id" : %%=v((@resident_preference_id))=%%
}
```

Comment: You're using a JQuery and attempting to access the DOM inside your Server Server Side JavaScript code. Your client and server side code need to be in separate scripts.

Comment: okay thankyou, i will move server side code to a separate script. Is there any other way to update data extension from DOM. I dont know which is the easier way to do this.

Comment: Your client-side code makes AJAX calls to a processing page that does the work of retrieving/updating data. That page runs server-side code.